# mysql Select array of values from another tables values

Tags: mysql

I have done several searches on this but sadly due to the type of query I am after it invariably gives me PHP answers.

I will revert to code to generate the script but the more I think about it I know there *must* be a simplier way to do it in a single query which will be much faster.

My Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
se.mailingID AS "mailingID",
(
    SELECT
        SUM(l.averageReadTime) 
    FROM
        eventlog AS l
    INNER JOIN sends as s ON l.mailingIDKey=s.id
    WHERE
        s.TFPIDSanitised=se.TFPIDSanitised
        AND
        l.averagerEadtIme!="-1"
        AND
        l.averageReadTime!="(none)"
) AS "Total",
(
    SELECT
        SUM(l.averageReadTime)
   FROM
        eventlog AS l
    INNER JOIN recipients AS r ON l.recipientKey=r.id
    INNER JOIN devices AS d ON r.commonDeviceKey=d.id
    INNER JOIN sends AS s ON l.mailingIDKey=s.id
    WHERE 
        d.name="AOL Mail"
        AND
        s.mailingID=se.mailingID
        AND
        l.averageReadTime!="-1"
        AND
        l.averageReadTime!="(none)"
) AS "AOL Mail",
...
[repeat for all email app types]
...
(
    SELECT
        SUM(l.averageReadTime)
    FROM
        eventlog AS l
    INNER JOIN recipients AS r ON l.recipientKey=r.id
    INNER JOIN devices AS d ON r.commonDeviceKey=d.id
    INNER JOIN sends AS s ON l.mailingIDKey=s.id
    WHERE
        d.name="AOL Desktop"
        AND
        s.mailingID=se.mailingID
        AND
        l.averageReadTime!="-1"
        AND
        l.averageReadTime!="(none)"
) AS "AOL Desktop"
FROM sends AS se
WHERE
    (
        se.sendDateTime BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-15 23:59:59'
    );
```

As you can see it is a monster of a query.

I am already considering removing one of the inner joins (the device name and just search on the devices.id bypassing the need for a 3rd JOIN).

What I am after, is to perform some sort of a loop within the query:

So its like (not real code I know)

```
SELECT LOOP (devices)
    where device.id=recipients.commonDeviceKey
    AS device.name
```

Is anything like this at all for mysql at all? I am going round in a loop (the irony of this is not lost on me) as mysql and loop do not bring up relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine something like this would work. I don't have your exact schema, but this should get what you need.

```
SELECT s.mailingID, SUM(l.averageReadTime), 'Total' as name
FROM eventlog AS l
  JOIN sends as s ON l.mailingIDKey=s.id
 WHERE
  l.averagerEadtIme!="-1"
  AND l.averageReadTime!="(none)"
  AND s.sendDateTime BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-15 23:59:59'

UNION ALL

SELECT s.mailingID, SUM(l.averageReadTime), d.name 
FROM eventlog AS l
  JOIN recipients AS r ON l.recipientKey=r.id
  JOIN devices AS d ON r.commonDeviceKey=d.id
  JOIN sends AS s ON l.mailingIDKey=s.id
 WHERE 
  l.averageReadTime!="-1"
  AND l.averageReadTime!="(none)"
  AND s.sendDateTime BETWEEN '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-01-15 23:59:59'
GROUP BY d.name
;
```

Comment: With a few tweaks the code *almost* works. (spelling mistake on averageReadTime, needed a second group by)

https://screencast.com/t/zXdP8oGafNjU

But the result is done in row format and not columns

what I'm after is this: 

https://screencast.com/t/Tnuv74Bt426X

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to find a more flexible approach, in the end I will have script in a loop to create a "devicesList" on the fly using the database but the below works.

Thanks for the help @Napoli whilst you may have not provided me with the answer you made me think along different lines (a 2 step process using linear tables for each device) for the solution.

```
def reports_engagement_device_archive():
    selectList = []
    selectString = ""
    devicesList = [
        "aoldesktop|4|AOL Desktop",
        "aolmail|14|AOL Mail",
        "appleipad|24|Apple iPad",
        "appleiphone|34|Apple iPhone",
        "applemail|44|Apple Mail",
        "blackberry|54|BlackBerry",
        "gmail|64|Gmail",
        "googleandroid|74|Google Android",
        "icloud|84|iCloud",
        "officethreesixfive|394|Office 365",
        "other|94|Other",
        "outlook|104|Outlook",
        "outlookcom|114|Outlook.com",
        "samsungemailapp|124|Samsung Email App",
        "samsungemailapp|134|Samsung Mail",
        "thunderbird|364|Thunderbird",
        "webversion|144|Web version",
        "windowslivemail|154|Windows Live Mail",
        "windowsmail|164|Windows Mail",
        "windowsphone|174|Windows Phone",
        "yahoomail|184|Yahoo! Mail"
    ]
    for devString in devicesList:
        (tblName, devID, devName) = devString.split("|")
        dropMySQLTable("temp_" + tblName ,verbose)
        selectList.append("""(SELECT SUM(t.total) FROM temp_""" + tblName + """ AS t WHERE t.mailingID=s.mailingID) AS \"""" + devName +  """\"""")
        db.sql("""
                CREATE TABLE temp_""" + tblName + """ AS (
                    SELECT s.mailingID,SUM(l.averageReadTime) AS "total" FROM eventlog AS l
                    INNER JOIN recipients AS r ON l.recipientKey=r.id
                    INNER JOIN sends AS s ON l.mailingIDKey=s.id
                    WHERE r.commonDeviceKey=""" + devID + """ AND l.averageReadTime!="-1" AND l.averageReadTime!="(none)" AND (s.sendDateTime BETWEEN '""" + startDate + """' AND '""" + endDate + """')
                    GROUP BY s.mailingID
                );
        """, verbose)
    selectString = ",".join(selectList)
    dropMySQLTable("t1" ,verbose)
    db.sql("""
        CREATE TABLE t1 AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT
            s.mailingID AS "mailingID"
            s.TFPIDSanitised AS "TFPID Sanitised",
            (SELECT SUM(l2.averageReadTime) FROM eventlog AS l2 INNER JOIN sends as s2 ON l2.mailingIDKey=s2.id WHERE s2.TFPIDSanitised=s.TFPIDSanitised AND l2.averageReadTime!="-1" AND l2.averageReadTime!="(none)") AS "Total",
            """ + selectString + """
            FROM sends AS s
            WHERE s.TFPIDSanitised IS NOT NULL
            AND (s.sendDateTime BETWEEN '""" + startDate + """' AND '""" + endDate + """')
        );
    """, verbose)
    for devString in devicesList:
        (tblName, devID, devName) = devString.split("|")
        dropMySQLTable("temp_" + tblName ,verbose)
```